# How to rebuild/regenerate Nuxt app when content from CMS changes

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, digital-ocean, strapi

I'm running a Nuxt app on DigitalOcean, it will build and regenerate the site when a new version is pushed. (I'm using  target: 'server' in config).

But because I'm using async to fetch the data from the headless CMS (Strapi), all the content will also be cached, so it will not update when data in the CMS is changed, only when I push new code.

How can I trigger some sort of Nuxt rebuild when the remote data changes? I'm using both GraphQL and REST for the contents.

There is an [article](https://strapi.io/blog/strapi-webhooks) on Strapi webhooks, but I'm not sure how to use that to trigger a rebuild command on Nuxt.

Comment: On services like Netlify, you can set a listener to a webhook, when Strapi updates the CMS, it will trigger a rebuild. Since you're using a VPS maintained by yourself here, you will need to implement the same approach yourself. Still, if you're doing a HTTP call to fetch the freshly updated data, shouldn't your thing take the latest data? It's not like you're using SSG here.

Comment: @kissu I can only trigger a redeploy on digitalocean, which should work but it takes about 3 minutes every time, while a rebuild would only takes 10 sec. But I guess there aren't many alternatives.

Comment: What do you use? Nuxt3? I doubt a build takes only 10s with Nuxt2. Also, what is the difference between a deploy on DO vs a rebuild? Not sure to get the difference. At the end, a build is not that fast overall nowadays if using Webpack + all the node_modules installation. There is also a [preview mode](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/live-preview#preview-mode) can be useful to not trigger a build for nothing. But if you have Strapi and you make an update, it may indeed take 3min every now and so (nothing shocking). Even tho, why not going SSG rather than SSR?

Comment: @kissu I use Nuxt3, when deploying Digitalocean will spin up a docker image, install all packages and then do a build. It would be faster if I could trigger only a rebuild inside the docker image. I tried using static, but then all the data from the API isn't cached locally, so it's way too slow. But I just read in the docs it should used cached data in static mode so maybe there's something wrong with my config.

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to cache it as well with SSG. Otherwise, don't rebuild it if you're using the SSR mode.